# Validate Proper Names (with Perl)

Tags: regex, perl, names

I have a census list of 150k last names, and trying to use this to validate the spelling of person names in an existing database.

Obviously there are many ethnic names in my database that don't match the census list, but are clearly not misspelled (Italian names like "Petroni", Swedish names like "Magnusdotter").

I would like to create a function (in Perl) to detect slight variations - i.e. likely mis-spellings - between names in the database and other *very popular* names in the census list (a frequency number is available).

I can imagine the algorithm, but before I dive in - any suggestions to do this in a reliable way - i.e. one that doesn't throw too many false positives?

Thanks!!

Comment: @PatrickJ.S. I think that's a bit harsh.  The question is about algorithms and techniques, not about writing the code.

Comment: @schwern: yeah, sorry, you'e right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially, you're writing a spell checker.  You may want to look into an Open Source, multi-lingual spell checker such as [Aspell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Aspell) and see what they do.  You might even be able to implement what you want as an aspell dictionary.

There are many algorithms for doing [approximate string matching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximate_string_matching). The [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) between words is one algorithm, and there are [several Perl modules to calculate it](https://metacpan.org/search?q=Levenshtein&size=20), but [Text::Fuzzy](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::Fuzzy) looks pretty good.

That's great for comparing a few words, but you have to choose between 150k.  You could just see if it's fast enough.  You could try caching the result.  But it remains an O(n) algorithm.  Instead (or in addition) you can create an index using a [phonetic matching algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonetic_algorithm).  Generally, these index words by what they sound like to allow matching on misspelled words.  Once you've generated the index for each word, you can match a new word against the index very quickly.  Obviously this is subject to cultural ideas of what words sound like which is why there are many algorithms each with different optimizations.  You can create several indexes using different algorithms and try them all.

You can even combine the two and do approximate string matching on the phonetic indexes.